# Godaddy contact form nightmare

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I have a website on Godaddy, with a contact form where visitors send me messages.

The contact page where people enter the messages has this action line in the code

```
form method="post" action="send.php"
```

This sends the data to the "send.php" file, which contains the following line of code for my email address where I receive the messages, and the subject of the received messages

```
mail("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "Form Submission","
```

This setup worked perfectly for several years. Then suddenly two weeks ago I stopped receiving the messages in my email. I went to the send.php file and changed the receiving email address thinking maybe my email account was blocking them, but it didn't work even though I tried 4 different email addresses from different providers.

I tried everything I could think of for hours, installed PHPMailer, nothing worked. Then finally by mere chance I changed the subject of the emails in the send.php file from "Form Submission" to "Feedback" and suddenly all started working!

Since I had tried several receiving emails and none worked, I was left with the conclusion that Godaddy was blocking messages titled "Form Submission" from being sent, probably by their internal spam filter or something. To be perfectly sure I went back to the send.php file and changed the subject of the emails to "Form Submission" and it stopped working and no emails showed up, then I changed to subject to other words and it worked every time.

I decided not to investigate further and accepted that the contact form worked fine with a new subject "Feedback", then after working flawlessly for two weeks it stopped again. You'd send a message, receive a normal success, but the emails do not show up in my email. Now that I know the issue I went and changed the subject of sent email in the send.php from "Feedback" to "Contact request", and it worked again.

Now I do not want to keep changing it, then suddenly godaddy's mysterious blocker blocks messages after a few weeks and I have to do it all over again. My questions are

1) Is there anyway I can disable whatever filter that suddenly decides that a certain "subject" will not go through?

2) Probably I won't be able to disable it, so would changing my mail exchange sittings in my godaddy account setup work, or will it still go through whatever it is on godaddy's site that blocks certain "subjects"?

3) My best bet now is to host the send.php file remotely, and I need help doing this. Is there a reliable free host where I can host my send.php file and use that host's email exchange system to send my site's messages? Also, if I host the file remotely, can I simply change the code in the input page itself which will remain on godaddy to be

```
form method="post" action="http://www.REMOTE-HOST.com/send.php"
```

instead of the current

```
form method="post" action="send.php"
```

Comment: Probably the receiver email server was  considering these emails as spam.please check spam folder.

Comment: Nothing in spam folders, and keep in mind I tried different email addresses from different providers. Only changing the subject in the "send.php" file makes it work.

Comment: I would use the service of an email provider (like mailchimp, sendgrid or other) to send the emails.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) we, I mean I had a webhost which was a nightmare working with, I do not want to go to details here. In one word PHPMailer saved me a lot of time and headache. You can install it using `composer` too if you are already using composer with the command `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`.